# Nepal internal flight prices based on passengers nationality

Tags: air-travel, indian-citizens, price, nepal, nepali-citizens

I'm planning my travel to Nepal for this Christmas holidays.

I'd like to book a ticket for an internal flight so I jumped on some local airlines websites.

I found out that is a common policy to differentiate prices for Indian and Nepalese citizens from all others.

For instance [Buddha Air](https://www.buddhaair.com), for the same flight, asks 99 USD for foreigners
[image: picture with Sat 17 Dec, USD 99]
and about 29 USD for locals
[image: picture with Sat 17 Dec, NPR 4003]
(Difference: locals gets 15+5kgs, foreigners get 25+5kgs; I'll travel with 10/12 kgs so I don't mind.)

With [Nepal Airlines](https://nepalairlines.com.np) seems even impossible to book a seat if you're not Nepalese or Indian
[image: picture with booking page for Nepal Airlines showing only the nationality options of Nepalese or Indian]

What sort of rule is this? Is it related to the Nepalese airlines very bad reputation?
Is there any way to get a discounted ticket as a tourist? Can local agencies make some kind of negotiation?

Comment: A later question about the same 'problem', neither seems a duplicate of the other: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/178450/why-are-some-flight-ticket-deals-localized

Answer (score 1):

This is reputed to happen all over the world and mostly less open.
And airlines do this because they can get away with it.

Can you as an international traveler not afford $US 100? For the locals their $30 may well be a months income.

You can of course ask any local travel agency whether they can book the cheaper fare for you, but do check that you can legally get it as a foreign tourist. It may well be that the country does pay towards their citizens travel and will not allow foreigners to travel this cheap, or it may be (hidden) taxes which locals do not need to pay but which foreigners do pay.

Comment: "Can you as an international traveler not afford $US 100?" I've never understood this point: as a tourist, I chose your country for my holidays, why you've to rob me? If a Nepalese pays, let's say, 2USD for a meal in a restaurant, why a tourist should pay 20 USD? If the meat for a steak for a Nepalese person costs 1USD, still costs 1USD for me! Am I supposed to repay them for the fast-fashion industry cancer?! Plus, also Bhutan, Bangladesh, ecc. are poor countries, why no discount for them? Your point about tax-supported fares would be interesting but I can't find anything about that.

Comment: I always feel that people from rich countries should not complain if the local prices are well below what they would pay at home but higher than the locals pay. Most locals will not eat in a restaurant where the meal is $20, they will go to the places where you can eat for $1. Those few citizens (relatively speaking) who can afford the higher prices will likely travel first class, to be seen to spend the money they have.

Comment: I'm not a fan of first class travels, I rather to stay in authentic places and leave a tip at the end... That said, I always try to treat all the people at the same way, I love travelling in poor countries but I hate to be seen as a piggy bank...

Comment: It seems that that rule was set to be [scraped](https://thehimalayantimes.com/nepal/agreement-inked-for-equal-airfare-for-foreigners-as-nepali), but nothing changed apparently

Comment: Sorry, this feels more like a moral  justification for hire prices but it's not actually answering the question.

Comment: The actual answer is 'because they can get away with it'.  But that is very thin.

Comment: @NicolasFormichella Cool! So I can book as a Nepalese and show that article at check-in!

Comment: @Matte.Car: you may not understand it, but companies want to get more profit as possible. And the price you see, their are not about the costs, but about how much profit they can do (supply/demand). In this case is just "market segmentation": if they think you will spend more, they charge you more.Very frequent, but well hidden. Again: they care about profit, not about being fair. (flights A->C and B->C are always more expensive than A->B->C, and B->A->C, same principle)

Comment: @Matte.Car Unfortunately, the world is not fair. If a flight costs $30 for a Nepalese, but $100 for a foreigner, it's not fair. If it costs $30 for both, it's not fair either, because what could be pocket money for a wealthy tourist is actually many days' wage for a poor local. Both of them work full time jobs (they can even do similar things!), but one earns much more that the other. I don't support nationality-based prices, but at the same time, if someone has disposable income for international leisure travel, they shouldn't be complaining about the world not being fair to them...

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Your example about connecting flights is extremely dependent on region, A LHR-LAX would be way less expensive than an LHR-JFK-LAX, and quite the contrary, getting a CDG-DUB-LAX (to benefit from Preclearance) is more expensive than getting the direct AF fight. This tends to apply way more when you have Europe-Asia flights though